# Establish uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of continuous functions, which converges to a continuous function $f$ on a compact set $E$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is Dini theorem